# Get only all parent WooCommerce categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am trying to get all the parent categories of WooCommerce, not the child.

```
$terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'product_cat','hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0]);
```

But it is not working. How can I get only parent categories?

Comment: I have updated my code, there was little typo errors … Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated 2** *(corrected little typo errors)*

Here is the way to get all parent categories only (you will get an array of **`WP_Term`** objects):

```
// Taxonomy for product categories
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';

// Get parent product categories
$parent_product_cats = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false ) );

// Iterating through each parent categories (WP_Term Objects)
foreach ( $parent_product_cats as $product_cat_obj ) {
    $term_id = $product_cat_obj->term_id; // term ID
    $term_name = $product_cat_obj->name; // term Name
    $term_slug = $product_cat_obj->slug; // term slug
}

// Testing the output
echo "<pre>All Product Parent categories "; print_r($parent_product_cats); echo "</pre>";
```

This code is tested and works.